# How to write a goal seek function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to write the following code in python?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Range("C5").GoalSeek goal:=Range("F5"), changingcell:=Range("B5")
End Sub
```

In this code, C5 is the cell that goal seek is solving for (where it places the result). F5 is the cell where the goal value resides, and B5 is the cell that goal seek will change to get C5 = F5

Comment: This is no site for *please write my code* and you provide no attempt on a solution, therefore this question is off-topic.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the goal seek function working in Python, as same as in Excel. Please see the script "ExampleScript.py" to see how it works.
The link: https://github.com/DrTol/GoalSeek_Python

Comment: Please add the code to your answer. Link only answers can become useless if the link dies.

Comment: This didnt work